# OR multiple filters for SQL Alchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

so I am trying to build multiple filters using python for sql alchemy calls. I

```
query = MyModel.query

if 'column1' in data:
    try:
        value = int(data['column1'])
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        query = query.filter(MyModel.column1 == value)

if 'column2' in data:
    try:
        value = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(data['column2']))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        query = query.filter(or_(MyModel.column2 >= value))

# etc.

return query
```

I am only doing this because the properties in the data object will vary and I do not know what I will get in terms of filter in the data object. Now when I execute the query...the statement **ANDs** both filters regardless of the **or_** I put in the second filter query. What do I need to change in order creating the query to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlalchemy: Produce OR-clause with multiple filter()-Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618051/sqlalchemy-produce-or-clause-with-multiple-filter-calls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gather the constraints first and then apply `or_`:

```
constraints = []
if 'column1' in data:
    try:
        value = int(data['column1'])
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        constraints.append(MyModel.column1 == value)

if 'column2' in data:
    try:
        value = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(data['column2']))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        constraints.append(MyModel.column2 >= value)

if constraints:
    query = query.filter(or_(*constraints))
```